# What does "search_for[strlen(search_for) - 1] = '\0';" mean?

Tags: c

I'm going through an introduction to programming in C book and I'm not sure what a line of code is doing.  I run the code with and without this statement, the result is the same.  I suspect that it is getting rid of the 'Enter' after the user inputs a string, but am not sure.  I'm assuming the authors wrote this line for a reason.  The character array is passed to a function that loops through an array of arrays and finds the text to search for using the 'strstr function.

```
int main () {
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Enter text to search for: ");
    scanf("%79s", search_for);
    search_for[strlen(search_for) -1] = '\0'; // why is this line here?
    find_track(search_for);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `scanf` and not a simple `fgets`? Because then it would actually make *some* sense.

Comment: it is definitely a scanf and not gets or fgets.

Comment: Well, in that case you have two answers divining all the sense (what there is of it) from the given code.

Comment: @jwhtsman Are you sure? It sounds like you're talking about "Head First C" and it's definitely **fgets** and not **scanf**. [See here](https://books.google.com/books?id=WaYatLKywDYC&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=%22search_for[strlen%28search_for%29+-1]+%3D+%27\0%27;%22&source=bl&ots=gsjzyLMbi4&sig=dVpYMIS3ogzKtsf2Sv1cDprTl0I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VtiQVNvrJsargwTdvIGYAQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22search_for[strlen%28search_for%29%20-1]%20%3D%20%27\0%27%3B%22&f=false).

Comment: Yes it is "Head First C".  I'm not sure if I have a different version of the book or what (I have the "physical book" and not a kindle or on line version) and it absolutely says that it is a scan formatted statement.  I do see that it says fgets where you're pointing me to.  Kind of weird I guess.  So my question now is, if it's fgets, why is the statement needed?

Comment: Just read another comment that answered that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It overwrites the last character of the the scanned string with a null character, shortening the string by one character. Why the programmer wanted to do such a thing I can't say.

Comment: It should be noted the string still takes up the same amount of space in memory; it just has extra null bytes on the end.

Comment: Yes, absolutely true. The declaration of `search_for` isn't affected, just its contents.

Comment: So is that what the author was doing?  He was just getting rid of the extra null zero?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If the input were `"abcdefg"`, it would be truncated to `"abcdef"`.

Comment: @Deduplicator Minor nit: The null-terminator is part of the string, though is does not count toward the value returned by `strlen()`.  "A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."

Comment: Interesting that `scanf("%79s", search_for);` can scan input that begin with `'\0'` and then `strlen(search_for)` would return 0 causing UB for `search_for[strlen(search_for) -1]` as it indexes beyond the range of `search_for[]`.

Comment: @chux: Nothing in either Posix nor standard C implies that a `%s` format in `scanf` will stop when it reads a NUL character, and a test with a standard linux install shows that glibc, at least, does not treat NUL as a terminator. Of course, one should test the return value from `scanf` in case EOF is reached, in which case using `search_for` would indeed be UB.

Answer (score 2):

It's a mistake. That code was written to be used with fgets not scanf.  Fgets adds a newline char to the end of the string the user enters and "search_for[strlen(search_for) -1] = '\0' " would overwrite that newline char with '\0'.

The problem: The code above with scanf causes the last character the user enters to be overwritten. So, a search using the string "ab" would only search for "a".

The program will work properly if "search_for[strlen(search_for) -1] = '\0'" is not included.

Answer (score 1):

Delete one character from the end of the "string" `search_for`.